# Why I can't instantiate a instance in the same module?

Tags: python

Suppose my module is `myclass.py`, and here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8

class A(object):
    b = B()
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class B(object):
    pass
```

and import it

```
In [1]: import myclass
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-e891426834ac> in <module>()
----> 1 import myclass

/home/python/myclass.py in <module>()
      2 # coding=utf-8
      3 
----> 4 class A(object):
      5     b = B()
      6     def __init__(self):

/home/python/myclass.py in A()
      3 
      4 class A(object):
----> 5     b = B()
      6     def __init__(self):
      7         pass

NameError: name 'B' is not defined
```

I know that if I define the class B above the class A, it is ok, there is no error. But, I don't want do that, are there any other methods to solve this. And I know that in C, there is function declaration.Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The class definition is a statement. When statement `AA` is executed, The statement of `BB` is not executed yet. Therefore, There is no class `B` yet and you get `NameError: name 'B' is not defined`

```
class A(object):
    b = B()              # <== AA
    def __init__(self):
        pass
class B(object):         # <== BB
    pass
```

To fix it:

---

You can change the order of classes:

```
class B(object):
    pass

class A(object):
    b = B()
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

---

You can move the statement which use the class `B` to `classmethod` and call it after the the defintion of class `B`:

```
class A(object):

    @classmethod
    def init(cls):
        cls.b = B()

    def __init__(self):
        pass

class B(object):
    pass

A.init()
```

Comment: I know that if I define the class B above the class A, it is ok, there is no error. But, I don't want do that, are there any other methods to solve this. And I know that in C, there is function declaration.Thank you!

Comment: `The class definition is a statement. When statement AA is executed, The statement of BB is not executed yet. Therefore, There is no class B yet and you get NameError: name 'B' is not defined`, yes I agree that. And can I declare the class `B` in module level, like C.

Comment: I think I can set  `A.b = B()` in `__init__()` of class A. But why that?

Comment: Well, This is not the thing. If you use `A.b = B()` in `__init__()` , A.b will be valid only when you create the first object of `A`. also it will created each time you create a object `A' . The class method will called only once - when the module is imported and therefore will be always valid.

Comment: @AlexanderYau You could, but it won't be available until you define at least one `A` instance.

Comment: @napuzba, thanks got it. I can only get class member when __init__() be called.

Comment: @AlexanderYau I think napzuba's solution is the cleanest you'll get in Python.

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you do it like so:

```
class A(object): 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.b = B() 

class B(object): 
    pass
```

**EDIT:** You can do it like this if you want to write all the definitions of the class after you have written class A.

```
class B:
    pass

class A(object): 
    b = B()
    def __init__(self): 
        pass 

class B(object): 
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

**EDIT 2:** Ignore the above solution, it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, b must be a class member , not a instance member

Comment: This won't work. The `A.b` class member will be the empty class you define originally. Add two different attributes to your `B` classes and you'll see

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga. I will try to look for other methods. But AFAIK, there's no way to forward declare in python because there are no declarations, only executable statements.

Comment: @ShubhamVasaikar Yes, honestly, OP should just live with defining the `B` class first.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any good reason to do what you are doing? In general this is quite dangerous pattern in Python.

In your case

```
class A(object):
    b = B()
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

You are binding an instance of B to the class A, which means that every instance of class A will **share the same instance** of class B. It's a case you must then handle properly.

In general you don't want this, If you want each instance of A to be related to an instance of B, you must make the assignment inside `__init__`

```
class A(object): 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.b = B()
```

In these case it doesn't meter where class B is defined, since it's instantiated at run time.

Again beware that the semantic is very different in the two cases (if you know Java, the former is more like defining a `static` attribute).

About:

> And I know that in C, there is function declaration

You shouldn't make too much parallels with a language like C, which is very different on many aspects, most important: it's a compiled language, that means that you code is parsed in it whole before being *translated* to machine language, that's why you can make function declaration and have your namespace populated regardless of the order you define things.

Python is an interpreted language, which means basically that each statement is *translated* when it's called and a class declaration is called when the module is imported.

So to recap: if you really need a class bound instance, you have to declare class B before class A, else you **must** instantiate B inside `__init__`, then you can declare B wherever you want (since it's called at runtime).